# Adobe Flex RichTextEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

is there any way to save text on adobe richtexteditor to text file or somethin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to save an TextFlow-Object into String or XML, there are two methods.
also you can import it. So you can save content of an TLF in database or whereever.

Import:

```
TextFlowUtil.importFromString(string) 
TextFlowUtil.importFromXML(xml)
```

Both methods offer an second parameter for the whitespaces.

Export:

```
outputTextArea.text = TextFlowUtil.export( inputTextArea.textFlow ).toXMLString();
```

BR Frank